# JavaScript code won't use onclick to style HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Recently, I was working on a toggle-style button setup for the [CodePen Challenge](https://codepen.io/challenges). I wanted to give the button a 3D appearance, so I set up a little JavaScript code that would use onclick to do this.

```js
var on = true
const green = document.getElementById('on')
const red = document.getElementById('off')
var greenOn = function() {
  if (on == false) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'inset -3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset'
    red.style.boxShadow = 'none'
    var on = true;
  }
}
var redOn = function() {
  if (on == true) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'none'
    red.style.boxShadow = '-3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset'
    var on = false
  }
}
```

Here's the code all nice and bundled into a code snippet.

```js
var on = true
const green = document.getElementById('on')
const red = document.getElementById('off')
var greenOn = function() {
  if (on == false) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'inset -3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset'
    red.style.boxShadow = 'none'
    var on = true;
  }
}
var redOn = function() {
  if (on == true) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'none'
    red.style.boxShadow = '-3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset'
    var on = false
  }
}
```

```css
.on {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.off {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.switch {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="switch">
    <button class="on" id="on" onclick="greenOn()"></button>
    <button class="off" onclick="redOn()" id="off"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I do it, nothing happens. Can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You are setting `var on = true` and `var on = false` in your function even after you have declared it globally, you are making a new variable on in function scope, that is why `on` is not changing.
   Change it to `on = false` and `on = true` to respective functions.
2. The value you applied to `box-shadow` property is not a valid value. Add a valid property value to see the changes.

```js
var on = true;
const green = document.getElementById('on');
const red = document.getElementById('off');
var greenOn = function() {
  if (!on) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'inset -3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)';
    red.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    on = true;
  }
}
var redOn = function() {
  if (on) {
    green.style.boxShadow = 'none';
    red.style.boxShadow = '-3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15)';
    on = false;
  }
}
```

```css
.on {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: lime;
  padding: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.off {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.switch {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="switch">
    <button class="on" id="on" onclick="greenOn()"></button>
    <button class="off" onclick="redOn()" id="off"></button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just needed a bit of tweaking (e.g. the red box shadow not being inset) but as of now good to go!

Answer (score 1):

You're *re-declaring local variables* with the same name as your global variables:

```
var on = true
//...
var greenOn = function() {
  //...
  var on = true
}
```

So within the scope of the function, `on` is not the `on` variable which was initially declared globally.  That's been shadowed by a new local variable which exists only within that function.  The variable declaration is hoisted, but its value is not.  So its value is `undefined` and this comparison will fail:

```
if (on == true) {
```

Don't re-declare the variables, just assign their values:

```
if (on == true) {
  green.style.boxShadow = 'none'
  red.style.boxShadow = '-3px 3px 13px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset'
  on = false // <--- here
}
```

---

As an aside, I highly encourage you to get in the habit of terminating your statements with semi-colons.  While JavaScript does allow for omitting those and performs automatic semi-colon insertion, it's a very common source of bugs.